# How to handle print dialog in Selenium using php-webdriver?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I am looking for a solution to handle the printer dialog using the facebook/php-webdriver.

I thought about using the WebDriverKeybord but it does not work.

`$this->driver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys(WebDriverKeys::ESCAPE);`

Comment: im not using facebook/php-webdriver but if this dialog is a browser dialog (like the download-dialog) than its not possible to control it. if this printer dialog behaves like a 2nd browser window you can easily navigate to it

Answer (score 0):

Print dialogue is not a part of the browser , so you can not use Selenium webdriver for it and has to be handles by some OS based automation software. You can use windows forms if u are running windows.

```
    SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
```